# Regex splitting of multiple grouped delimeters

Tags: python, python-re

How do you group a combination of delimiters, such as `1.` or `2)`?

For example, given a string like, `'1. I like food! 2. She likes 2 baloons.'`, how can you separate such a sentence?

As another example, given the input

```
'1) 3D Technical/Process animations, 2) Explainer videos, 3) Product launch videos'
```

the output should be

```
['3D Technical', 'Process animations', 'Explained videos', 'Product launch videos']
```

I tried:

```
a = '1) 3D Technical/Process animations, 2) Explainer videos, 3) Product launch videos'
re.split(r'[1.2.3.,1)2)3)/]+|etc', a)
```

The output was:

```
['',
 'D Technical',
 'Process animations',
 ' Explainer videos',
 ' Product launch videos']
```

Comment: is `/` the only character to split  on in a sentence ?

Comment: is there always a comma ?

Comment: Your first example is more general than what you actually seem to need. Do you really need to handle `1.`?

Comment: What does `etc` mean in your regex?

Comment: `etc` just to avoid if there's any sentence ending with `etc`.

Comment: I need to handle `1.` and similar items. That's why I asked how to split with multiple 'grouped delimeters'.

Comment: So your question is "what is a regular expression that matches a digit followed by `)` or `.`"?

Comment: Yeah in a way.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get the expected result:

```
import re

a = '1) 3D Technical/Process animations, 2) Explainer videos, 3) Product launch videos'
r = [s for s in map(str.strip,re.split(r',? *[0-9]+(?:\)|\.) ?', a)) if s]

print(*r,sep='\n')
3D Technical/Process animations
Explainer videos
Product launch videos
```

- The pattern `r',? *[0-9]+(?:\)|\.) ?'` for the separators can be broken down as follows:

  - `,?` an optional trailing comma
  - `*` an optional space (or many) preceding the number
  - `[0-9]+` a sequence of at least one digit
  - `(?:\)|\.)` followed by a closing parenthesis or a period.  The `?:` at the begining makes it a non-capturing group so that re.split doesn't include it in the output
  - `?` an optional space after the parenthesis or period (you may want to remove the ? or replace it with a + depending on your actual data

The output of re.split is mapped to str.strip to remove leading/trailing spaces.  This is inside a list comprehension that will filter out empty strings (e.g. preceding the first separator)

If commas or slashes without the numbering are also used as separators, you can add that to the pattern:

```
def splitItems(a):
    pattern = r'/|,|(?:,? *[0-9]+(?:\)|\.) ?)'
    return [s for s in map(str.strip,re.split(pattern, a)) if s]
```

output:

```
a = '3D Technical/Process animations, Explainer videos, Product launch videos'
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')

3D Technical/Process animations
Explainer videos
Product launch videos


a = '1. Hello 2. Hi'
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')
Hello
Hi

a = "Great, what's up?! , Awesome"
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')
Great
what's up?!
Awesome

a = '1. Medicines2. Devices 3.Products'
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')
Medicines
Devices
Products

a = 'ABC/DEF/FGH'
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')
ABC
DEF
FGH
```

If your separators are a list of either-or patterns (meaning only one pattern applies consistently for a given string), then you can try them in order of precedence in a loop and return the first split that produces more than one part:

```
def splitItems(a):
    for pattern in ( r'(?:,? *[0-9]+(?:\)|\.) ?)', r',', r'/' ):
        result = [*map(str.strip,re.split(pattern, a))]
        if len(result)>1: break
    return [s for s in result if s]
```

Output:

```
# same as all the above and this one:

a = '1. Arrangement of Loans for Listed Corporates and their Group Companies, 2. Investment Services wherein we assist Corporates, Family Offices, Business Owners and Professionals to invest their   Surplus Funds to invest in different products such as Stocks, Mutual Funds, Bonds, Fixed Deposit, Gold Bonds,PMS etc 3. Estate Planning'
print(*splitItems(a),sep='\n')

Arrangement of Loans for Listed Corporates and their Group Companies
Investment Services wherein we assist Corporates, Family Offices, Business Owners and Professionals to invest their   Surplus Funds to invest in different products such as Stocks, Mutual Funds, Bonds, Fixed Deposit, Gold Bonds,PMS etc
Estate Planning
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and minimally explain your code if possible?

Comment: `'3D Technical/Process animations, Explainer videos, Product launch videos'`
This doesn't work for this example, can u please check.

Comment: There are 3 types of data, `1. Hello 2. Hi` `Great, what's up?! , Awesome`  `1. Medicines2. Devices 3.Products` . Also, data like, `ABC/DEF/FGH`

Comment: Alright, not trying to confuse you but please modify the code such that it works for the sentence in first comment of this answer as well as the sentence in your answer. It'll fix 90% of issues in my original problem. :p

Comment: OMG the new edited code works greatt!!
Just one last thing: `'1. Arrangement of Loans for Listed Corporates and their Group Companies, 2. Investment Services wherein we assist Corporates, Family Offices, Business Owners and Professionals to invest their   Surplus Funds to invest in different products such as Stocks, Mutual Funds, Bonds, Fixed Deposit, Gold Bonds,PMS etc 3. Estate Planning'`
Can you please modify the code such that, split sentences like above with just numbers prefix to them.

Comment: Expected Output: 
`['Arrangement of Loans for Listed Corporates and their Group Companies',
 'Investment Services wherein we assist Corporates, Family Offices, Business Owners and Professionals to invest their   Surplus Funds to invest in different products such as Stocks, Mutual Funds, Bonds, Fixed Deposit, Gold Bonds,PMS etc',
 'Estate Planning']`

Comment: This would be ambiguous because the separation based on single commas would stop working if the pattern had to include parts that contain commas.  Alternatively, you could have the function try multiple patterns in order of precedence.

Comment: In order of precedence yes. `1.2.3....1)2)3) > , > /` . This should be the order if we're trying to split in an order of precedence. Idk how. Please don't change the above code, if possible try to write a new code to split in the order above. It's too much to ask, sorry about it.!

Comment: New code works but not on the first sentence, `'3D Technical/Process animations, Explainer videos, Product launch videos'` 

Comment: I forgot the `r` in front of the pattern strings (pasted the wrong version), fixed it now, try again.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Thank you so much!